# flutter dynamic list widgets removing not working

Tags: flutter, forms, dart, listview, drop-down-menu

in my flutter app I'm using a dynamic form in which the user adds more fields based on their info. this form consists of two textfields and one dropdown. what I want to achieve is as follows.
[image: sample image]

the issue I'm facing is that when I remove a certain form group it removes from the last index but the value of the form is removed correctly. but the value from the UI removed is the last one. for the textfields I can create controller and manage with the through dispose method. but how can I make it work for the dropdown as well?

```
import 'package:dropdown_button2/dropdown_button2.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Purchased extends StatefulWidget {
  const Purchased({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Purchased> createState() => _PurchasedState();
}

class _PurchasedState extends State<Purchased> {
  List<UserInfo> list = [];
  List<TextEditingController> textControllerList = [];
  List<TextEditingController> textControllerList1 = [];
  Map<String, String> listCtrl = {};
  @override
  void dispose() {
    textControllerList.forEach((element) {
      element.dispose();
    });
    textControllerList1.forEach((element) {
      element.dispose();
    });
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          /// every time you add new Userinfo, it will generate new FORM in the UI
          list.add(UserInfo());
          setState(() {}); // dont forget to call setState to update UI
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: list.length,
                itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      Text('phone'),
                      Text(list[index].phone),
                      Text('email'),
                      Text(list[index].email),
                      Text('category'),
                      Text(list[index].category)
                    ],
                  );
                })),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: list.length,
                itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
                  TextEditingController controller1 = TextEditingController();
                  textControllerList.add(controller);
                  textControllerList1.add(controller1);
                  return MyForm(
                      // dont forget use the key, to make sure every MyForm is has identity. to avoid missed build
                      textEditingController: textControllerList[index],
                      textEditingController1: textControllerList1[index],
                      key: ValueKey(index),
                      //pass init value so the widget always update with current value
                      initInfo: list[index],
                      dataCtrl: listCtrl,
                      // every changes here will update your current list value
                      onChangePhone: (phoneVal) {
                        if (phoneVal != null) {
                          list[index].setPhone(phoneVal);
                          setState(() {});
                        }
                      },
                      // every changes here will update your current list value
                      onchangeEmail: (emailVal) {
                        if (emailVal != null) {
                          list[index].setEmail(emailVal);
                          setState(() {});
                        }
                      },
                      onchangeCategory: (categoryVal) {
                        if (categoryVal != null) {
                          list[index].setCategory(categoryVal);

                          setState(() {});
                        }
                      },
                      onremove: () {
                        list.removeAt(index);
                        textControllerList.removeAt(index);
                        textControllerList1.removeAt(index);
                        if (listCtrl.containsKey(index)) {
                          listCtrl.remove(index);
                        }
                        setState(() {});
                      });
                })),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyForm extends StatefulWidget {
  final UserInfo initInfo;
  final Function(String?) onChangePhone;
  final Function(String?) onchangeEmail;
  final Function(String?) onchangeCategory;
  final TextEditingController textEditingController;
  final TextEditingController textEditingController1;
  Map<String, String> dataCtrl = {};
  final VoidCallback? onremove;
  MyForm({
    key,
    required this.initInfo,
    required this.onChangePhone,
    required this.onchangeEmail,
    required this.onchangeCategory,
    required dataCtrl,
    required this.onremove,
    required this.textEditingController,
    required this.textEditingController1,
  });

  @override
  State<MyForm> createState() => _MyFormState();
}

class _MyFormState extends State<MyForm> {
  TextEditingController _phoneCtrl = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _emailCtrl = TextEditingController();
  String? selected;

  final List<String> category = [
    'Manager',
    'Reception',
    'Sales',
    'Service',
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // set init value
    _phoneCtrl = TextEditingController(text: widget.initInfo.phone);
    _emailCtrl = TextEditingController(text: widget.initInfo.email);
    selected = widget.initInfo.category;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          IconButton(onPressed: widget.onremove, icon: Icon(Icons.remove)),
          TextFormField(
            controller: widget.textEditingController,
            onChanged: widget.onChangePhone,
          ),
          TextFormField(
            controller: widget.textEditingController1,
            onChanged: widget.onchangeEmail,
          ),

          DropdownButtonFormField2(
              //key: _key,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                isDense: true,
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                ),
              ),
              isExpanded: true,
              hint: const Text(
                'Select Category',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
              ),
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                color: Colors.black45,
              ),
              iconSize: 30,
              buttonHeight: 60,
              //value: category[1],
              buttonPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 10),
              items: category
                  .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: item,
                        child: Text(
                          item,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ))
                  .toList(),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value == null) {
                  return 'Please select Catagory.';
                }
              },
              onChanged: widget.onchangeCategory,
              onSaved: (value) {
                widget.onchangeCategory;
                if (widget.dataCtrl.containsKey('${widget.key}') &&
                    value != null) {
                  widget.dataCtrl['${widget.key}'] = value.toString();
                }
              })

          /// same like TextFormField, you can create new widget below
          /// for dropdown, you have to 2 required value
          /// the initValue and the onchage function
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class UserInfo {
  ///define
  String _phone = '';
  String _email = '';
  String _category = '';

  /// getter
  String get phone => _phone;
  String get email => _email;
  String get category => _category;

  ///setter
  void setPhone(String phone) {
    _phone = phone;
  }

  void setEmail(String email) {
    _email = email;
  }

  void setCategory(String category) {
    _category = category;
  }
}
```

screenshot of the problem. check the category list from the text above vs the dropdown value.

[image: this is after index removed]

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a bit confusing, i tried to reproduce your error and something came to my attention:

The problem seems to be with the dropdown, as the text fields reset correctly.

You initialize your data in the initState in MyForm, however when you change a category for example, this is no longer called. So I moved that out to the build method. Also I have passed a value to the dropdown. This made it work for me:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _phoneCtrl = TextEditingController(text: widget.initInfo.phone);
    _emailCtrl = TextEditingController(text: widget.initInfo.email);
    selected = widget.initInfo.category;
```

Add this to your DropdownButton

```
value: selected!.isEmpty ? null : selected,
```

Comment: it didn't work. I added the screenshot above

Comment: Did you made any changes to your code? I just copied your code and added my changes and it worked.

Comment: And the problem should be the same. You have to give the DropDown a value, set selected inside build since initState is called only once